# url changing templete not loading ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am not able to redirect from one page to another.

I can route from Splashscreen to topicscreen but when I calling splashScreen from topic my controller executes but templets not loading again.
what to do..
I am using `$state.go('topicScreen');` for redirecting from one page to other.
I am able to to go top to down url as defined in  config.

getting this error while running in android device

```
W/BindingManager Cannot call determined Visibility() - never saw a connection for the
```

my config

```
ionicApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider
  .state('splashScreen', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/splashScreen',
    views: {
      'splashScreen': {      
        templateUrl: 'templates/splashScreen.html',
        controller: 'SplashScreenCtrl'
      }
    }
  }).state('topicScreen', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/topicScreen',
    views: {
      'topicScreen': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/topicScreen.html',
        controller: 'GridController'
      }
    }
  }).state('questionList', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/topicScreen/:id/:description/:icon/questionList',
    views: {
      'questionList': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/questionList.html',
        controller: 'QuesController'
      }
    }
  }).state('answerPage', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/topicScreen/:category_id/:id/answerPage',
    views: {
      'questionList': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/answerPage.html',
        controller: 'AnsController'
      }
    }
  }).state('costumQues', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/costumQues/:category_id',
    views: {
      'costumQues': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/costumQues.html',
        controller: 'CostomQuesController'
      }
    }
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/splashScreen');

});
```

my Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/dbServices.js"></script>
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter">
      <ion-nav-view name="splashScreen"></ion-nav-view>
      <ion-nav-view name="topicScreen"></ion-nav-view>
      <ion-nav-view name="questionList"></ion-nav-view>
      <ion-nav-view name="answerPage"></ion-nav-view>
      <ion-nav-view name="costumQues"></ion-nav-view>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add in comments if u edit the post with meaning.Also If not clear then create concrete example in codepen.Also take some time togive detail meaning to question

Comment: please put concreate  codepen Or Plunkr example

Answer (score 0):

In angular I have used **when** which worked for me

```
$routeProvider.when('/sales', {
    templateUrl : 'sales.html',
    controller : 'salesCtrl'

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try only this in your html file:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view ></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```